# sorting article by class with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, class, sorting, checkbox

I try to sort out the members of a team by the function they has in the company.

actually it sorts with an AND function:
If member A has function 1 and member B has function 2 and I select the checkboxes for function 1 and for function 2 it will show me member A and member B

**but now I need an OR function:**

so if member A has function 1 and function 2 and member B has function 2 and I select checkbox for function 1 and for function 2 it should show me only member 1 because he has both functions

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function()
{
     var $lis = $('.results > article').hide();
     //For each one checked
     var numChecked = $('input:checked').each(function()
     {
          $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
     }).length;

    if (!numChecked) $lis.show();
});
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="squad results">
    <article class="function1 function2 function3 ">
        <p class="member-name"><b>Member A</b></p>
    </article>
    <article class="function1">
        <p class="member-name"><b>Member B</b></p>
    </article>
    <article class="function2 ">
        <p class="member-name"><b>Member C</b></p>
    </article>
</section>
```

How can I simple change this to sort by OR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, you show the filtered "rel" in the `.each()` loop.

If you just collect all those instead... You will be able to use it as one selector (concatenated string).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('div.tags').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(){
    var $lis = $('.results > article').hide();
    //For each one checked
    var rels = "";
    var numChecked = $('input:checked').each(function(){
      rels += '.' + $(this).attr('rel');  // Concatenate it as a string.
    }).length;

    if (!numChecked){
      $lis.show();
    }else{
      $(rels).show();  // Use the resulting string as a selector.
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags">
  <input type="checkbox" rel="function1">Function 1
  <input type="checkbox" rel="function2">Function 2
  <input type="checkbox" rel="function3">Function 3
</div>

<section class="squad results">
  <article class="function1 function2 function3 ">
    <p class="member-name"><b>Member A</b></p>
  </article>
  <article class="function1">
    <p class="member-name"><b>Member B</b></p>
  </article>
  <article class="function2 ">
    <p class="member-name"><b>Member C</b></p>
  <article>
</section>
```

[`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was deprecated in jQuery 3.0... I suggest the use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which has a similar syntax.